# Experience Optimization active tests aren't counting visitors

Tags: personalization, rules-engine, content-testing, experience-optimization

**Version 9.2.0**

## Summary

After creating a content test, the number of visitors aren't reducing on page visits nor does it seem to be selecting content based on the **Percentage of visitors exposed to the test** setting. Because of this, no results are available so they're constantly stuck on 0 everything.

## Details

This is happening on my **local** instance. First it wasn't working with a personalization rule, then I tried a simple predefined and custom rule (separately) to both always return true and it wasn't respecting the visitor exposure percentage parameter set. Set up of the test is pretty much the default options.

Observed during new sessions (different browser), it'll show option A immediately and then only ever show option B for the remainder of that session.

Not sure if it's worth mentioning but the Preview and start test screen where it shows different variations is grey and spinning indefinitely.

## Attempts at trying to fix it or at least go in the right direction

1. Rebuild **sitecore_testing_index** where possible
2. Hitting the page on a combination of different browsers + private browsing sessions
3. Ensure no caching is being used on the rendering
4. Deploy the actual test item (within `test lab`)
5. Verify xDB and Tracking are both enabled
6. Logs show the errors:

   - `Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator/pathAnalyzerLiveAvent`
   - `Workflow state could not be retrieved for item with id {/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Dimensions/Pages/By entry page URL/All visits by entry page URL}`
7. Nothing is being overridden in `Sitecore.ContentTesting.config`

<s>I will try setting it up on the business servers tomorrow to see if it's anything local that's preventing this from working.</s>  I tried this and no difference to the result.

## Potentially related issue if you have time

I was originally trying to do this with personalization rules but turned out not to work. It was a predefined rule containing two with:

- Pattern cards
- Page events

### Summary

This was set up with a similar content test to above. According to the rules, once the user is exposed to the page, the content should stay the same indefinitely for the session yet between soft refreshes it was changing seemingly at random. This was being observed in a live environment, within my local I don't see any switch at all (stays default indefinitely)

Is the session not getting "saved" and therefore not counting? Or am I unrealistic in expecting that the results would show up almost immediately? (probably have waited half a day max before cancelling the test and trying something else.

### What I've tried

1. Verify that other pages on the site have the correct **Page event** and **Pattern card** attached
2. Set up my own custom rule condition with the exact same format/item as one given by SC; then used a decompiler to have the same code to debug locally
3. Contact profile weren't picking up the profile cards nor was the page event by the interaction

So the image below is what I see at all times no matter how many times I view the page.

[image: Test results screen]

**Update**

Just saw [Component's personalization rule applies only once](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23768/components-personalization-rule-applies-only-once#) and I'm observing the same thing here. Unsure if it's related but that question never got answered.

Comment: Are analytics setting proper? Or, check in the console if you have any errors in the console.

Comment: Thanks @PrashantTomar for the comment, what analytics settings specifically are you talking about?
And no console errors that I can see related to anayltics.